# Is there a photo processing library for android?

Tags: android, iphone, image-processing

I need a library that allows me to shrink the image (file size) and correct White balance, Exposure and Saturation from a photo taken from the camera.  I need this to work on android mobiles and tablets and it would be a bonus if the same library was available for IPhone.

Does anybody have any experience with such a library?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the [ColorMatrixColorFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrixColorFilter.html) class to directly edit the color values in you image.

I've never used it, but the [android-image-filtering](http://code.google.com/p/android-image-filtering/) project looks promising if you want some more advanced stuff.

You're probably not going to find a library that works on both Android and iPhone since Android uses java and the iPhone uses objective-c.

Comment: Thanks I'll check them out. I was hoping there might be something that was ported to both platforms, like box2d is.

Comment: I've had a look at those and they are both methods of applying a color filter. They don't have methods for compression, exposure, saturation and white balance.